# Can slack incoming webhooks post message to all private groups?

Tags: slack-api

I was searching if slack incoming webhooks can send message to all private groups, but I didn't find any slack documentation on that.

So, can slack incoming webhooks send message to all private groups?

Comment: Did you get an answer to this?

Answer (score 15):

Incoming webooks can post to private groups.  When you set up the incoming webhook at `https://TEAM.slack.com/services/new/incoming-webhook`, choose the private group you want to send to.

You can send to a different channel (including a different private group) with the `"channel"` JSON key.

A single incoming webhook cannot send to multiple destinations.

Comment: `A single incoming webhook cannot send to multiple destinations.` Is this still the case?

Comment: It is.  The `channel` JSON key is a single string, not an array of channels to send the message to.

Comment: Not to multiple destinations at once, but you can set different `channel` value for different hook calls.

Comment: Note that there are two types of "incoming webhook" now. The default type is create as part of a Slack app, and the legacy type needs to be installed as app from the Slack App Directory. Only the legacy type supports multiple destinations.

Comment: But can you still sent to a private channel, even if you didn't select it during setup?

Comment: Does the person creating the webhook need to be a member of the private channel?

Comment: @LeviPutna If the user is not a member of the channel, the webhook fails with an error of "channel_not_found"